# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found python

Tags: python

I am beginner and i don't know much about python. While i wanted to code a program that can generate flexible codes and wanted to add random numbers in it, i get this errror. Could you please help me?? TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

code:

````
import random
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase 
numbers = (0,9)

codeamt = int(input('how many?: '))
codelnt = int(input('how many in one block?: '))
codeblockamt = int(input('how many blocks: '))

for i in range (codelnt):
    code = ''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase and  numbers) for i in range (codelnt)).join(choice(ascii_uppercase and numbers) for i in range(codelnt))

for i in range (codeamt):
    print('-'.join(''.join(choice(ascii_uppercase and numbers) for k in range (codelnt)) for j in range(codeblockamt)))```
````

Comment: What do you expect `numbers` to contain? that also isn't how to concatenate two strings together if it were to be a string

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output?

Comment: `numbers` is a tuple of `int`s. You can't use an `int` within a `str.join()` function call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're expecting `(0,9)` to give you all the numbers between 0-9 which isn't the case, it just creates a tuple. `range(0,9)` might be closer but even that won't help when you just use them for string purposes.

Just make a string with the desired digits and then concatenate your strings correctly

```
from string import digits
numbers = digits
   or 
numbers = "0123456789"


choice(ascii_uppercase + numbers)
```